# colored geom bar - plotly

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggplotly

How do you resolve the double labels when you hover over the filled geom_bar? This doesn't occur in the unfilled geom_bar

```
# no fill
library(plotly)

dat <- data.frame(
   time = factor(c("Lunch","Dinner"), levels=c("Lunch","Dinner")),
   total_bill = c(14.89, 17.23)
)

p <- ggplot(data=dat, aes(x=time, y=total_bill)) +
   geom_bar(stat="identity")

p <- ggplotly(p)

# filled

library(plotly)

dat <- data.frame(
   time = factor(c("Lunch","Dinner"), levels=c("Lunch","Dinner")),
   total_bill = c(14.89, 17.23)
)

p <- ggplot(data=dat, aes(x=time, y=total_bill, fill=time)) +
   geom_bar(stat="identity")

p <- ggplotly(p)
```

source: https://plot.ly/ggplot2/geom_bar/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This repeat arises because you have `time` in your `aes` call twice (`x` and `fill`, which is common).

You just need to specify which arguments in `aes` you want to use in the graph with the `tooltip` argument.

```
p <- ggplot(data=dat, aes(x=time, y=total_bill, fill=time)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity")

p <- ggplotly(p, tooltip = c("x", "y"))
```

In this case, I used `"x"` and `"y"`, but you could also have used `"fill"` instead.

Alternatively, you can also force labels (which sometimes comes in handy) like the following:

```
p <- ggplot(data=dat, aes(x=time, y=total_bill, fill=time,
                          label = time, label2 = total_bill)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity")

p <- ggplotly(p, tooltip = c("label", "label2"))
```